# how to dispatch an event which has already been dispatched in javascript?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am trying to dispatch an event to two levels as below

client <--- APIwrapper <-- platformcode

But when I do a dispatchEvent(event) at the API layer it throws an error as object does not exists at this level.
I need to dispatch the same event what should i be doing.

Answer (score 0):

you should put your scripts tags at the end of html codes like this:

```
<body>
  .
  .
  html tags
  .
  .
  <script>
   .
   .
   .
   your codes
  </script>
</body>
```

or

put your scripts in `$(document).ready(function(){...your codes...})`